# Mongoose not hashing the password on update

Tags: express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Here's my schema.

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    display_name: { type: String },
    profile_pic: { type: String },
    cover_pic: { type: String },
    groups: { type: Array },
    posts: { type: Array },
    following: { type: Array },
    followers: { type: Array },
    bio: { type: String },
  },
  { versionKey: false, timestamps: true }
);

userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  console.log(this.isModified("password"));
  if (!this.isModified("password")) return next();

  const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, 8);
  this.password = hash;
  return next();
});

userSchema.methods.checkPassword = function (password) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};
```

I'm updating the password using findOneAndUpdate. And it is getting stored directly without the hash.

Answer (score 0):

As per mongoose documentation, while calling `findOneAndUpdate` (or other functions, which are using helper findOneAndModiy), `pre` and `post` hooks are not triggered. You should use the traditional method `.save()`.

From mongoose documentation:

> Although values are cast to their appropriate types when using the findAndModify helpers, the following are not applied:
> 1 defaults
> 2 setters
> 3 validator
> 4 middleware
> If you need those features, use the traditional approach of first retrieving the document.

If you are using mongoose >v4.0, you can use `runValidators`. [more details here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/860)